# Чтение события из другой программы

Tags: c#, .net, события

Есть 2 программы. 1 работает в фоне(далее ФП) другая в оконном режиме(далее ОП).
Необходимо чтобы по нажатию кнопки в ОП, ФП выполняла какойто код. Необходимо чтобы ОП не передавала в ФП, а ФП читала событие ОП. Возможно ли это сделать? Если возможно то как?

Comment: Свяжите их через WCF с подходящим биндингом. На дуплексном биндинге можно получить полностью событийную модель. В качестве бонуса получите легкое удаленное управление добавив еще один подходящий биндинг в конфиг.

Comment: Ещё как вариант, который давно существует в сервисах - подписка на события папки (DirectoryWatcher какой-нибудь). Создаете в специальной папке файл на событие, второй программой реагируете.

Comment: + как вариант winApi, получаете список foreground окон на рабочем столе, получаете нужное вам окно, затем слушаете сообщения и соответственно на них реагируете.